# Get dimension of rectangular polygon PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql

Is there a way to calculate the width and height of a rectangular polygon such as the following?

```
POLYGON((530934.26 161504.25,
         530941.99 161515.92,
         530945.36 161513.76,
         530937.66 161502.06,
         530934.26 161504.25))
```

I was trying to go on the root of calculating the diagonal `ST_MaxDistance(geom, geom)` and area  `st_area(geom)` and their by get to the dimensions in a mathematical way but doesn't look like it is straight forward.

Comment: So do you want to get the lengths of the sides of http://postgis.net/docs/ST_OrientedEnvelope.html?

Comment: @user30184 not sure the direction. I tried `ST_AsText(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geom))` and get the output as `POLYGON((530934.266697057 161504.258440467,530937.63710994 161502.0254556,530945.395827638 161513.736274812,530942.025414755 161515.96925968,530934.266697057 161504.258440467))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the lengths of the perpendicular sides you can just extract the first three coordinates and find the distances between them, as shown here:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 'POLYGON((530934.26 161504.25, 530941.99 161515.92,  530945.36 161513.76,   530937.66 161502.06, 530934.26 161504.25))'::geometry 
         AS geom
)
SELECT  ST_Distance(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1),
                    ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2)) AS d1, 
        ST_Distance(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2),
                    ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3)) AS d2 
  FROM data;
```