# Detecting polygon shape with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, utm

I've got a polygon table with a UTM 10x10 km grid in a PostgreSQL/PostGIS database and I need to identify those cells that are not a regular square (i.e. changes in UTM numbers):

[image]

Following the comments below, I've built this code to calculate the difference in lenght of two consecutive sides of each cell:

```
with tabla as (
     select utmcode, 
                ST_Distance(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 1),
                ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2)) AS d1, 
                ST_Distance(ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 2),
                ST_PointN(ST_ExteriorRing(geom), 3)) AS d2
     from malla_p)
select utmcode, abs(round(d1-d2)) AS difference         
from tabla          
                ;
```

But it returns, for example, `difference` = 0 for this cell:

[image]

or `difference` = 498 for this other:

[image]

How can it be solved?

Comment: Check out this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/366837/120129

Comment: Do you know where to download your grid? Or did you create it yourself?

Comment: @BERA I have downloaded it from an official repository (Spanish Ministry of Environment) and I'm pretty sure that it is correct. https://www.miteco.gob.es/en/biodiversidad/servicios/banco-datos-naturaleza/informacion-disponible/bdn-cart-aux-descargas-ccaa.aspx

Comment: why not just selecting geometries whose area is not 100km2?

Comment: the issue with computing distances between points is that you must be sure that the polygon has only 4 points (+1 for the last point)

Comment: Possible workflow - extract vertices > split exterior rings with vertices > count number of segments/flag polygons with more than 4 > flag polygons with less than 2 matching segment lengths.

Comment: What happens if: SELECT * FROM malla_p WHERE ST_Area(geom)!=ST_Area(ST_Envelope(geom));

Answer (score 5):

Modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62467829/python-check-if-shapely-polygon-is-a-rectangle.

Select polygons having an area that does not match the area of the oriented envelope https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OrientedEnvelope.html of the polygon.

```
SELECT * from the_table 
where ST_Area(geometry)!=
ST_Area(ST_OrientedEnvelope(geometry));
```

Comment: This also selects cells like this one https://cloud.mail.ru/public/FF7M/xHBBS2LZD that, although being a regular square, are not in a "vertical" position

Comment: You should probably add some tolerance depending on the application - probably don't need full floating point accuracy - `where round(st_area(geom)::numeric,1) != round(st_area(st_orientedenvelope(geom))::numeric,1)` - adjust the rounding to suit your level of tolerance.